# How to type narrow a union type of object and string on an object property?

Tags: typescript

I get an array of objects from an api as an `Expense[]` type that has a `due` property that is a `Timestamp` type object. I want to get the `seconds` property from the `due` object and format it into a string to display in the UI. I can't seem to narrow the type to properly access `.seconds`.  This is in Angular but that shouldn't matter. I can cast the type as shown below but I want to avoid casting. I also tried using the `in` keyword and attempted with `satisfies`, but couldn't seem to get it. Am I approaching this completely wrong? How do I type narrow this properly?

*Code simplfied for brevity*

```
interface Timestamp {
  seconds: number;
  nanoseconds: number;
}

interface Expense {
  name: string;
  amount: number;
  remaining: number;
  due: Timestamp | string;
  notes: string;
  category: string;
}

this.expenses = expenses.map((expense) => {
        if (typeof expense.due !== 'string') {
          return { ...expense, due: this.formatDate(expense.due.seconds * 1000) } as Expense;
        }
      }) as Expense[];

formatDate(milliseconds: number) {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-ca', {
      weekday: 'short',
      day: 'numeric',
      year: 'numeric',
    }).format(new Date(milliseconds));
  }
```

Comment: Is this a [mre]? I had to add a little extra code to avoid errors from this being just a snippet, and once I resolved errors that seemed unrelated (e.g., "not all paths return a value") then I don't see any problem at all.  That is, [this is the code](https://tsplay.dev/NlzjQW) and it looks fine to me.  What exactly is the issue here? Could you [edit] to make the code such that if anyone copies it into their own IDEs they'll immediately see the issue you're having and only that issue?

Comment: Sounds like your map is not returning anything in case that `expense.due` is a `string`. Maybe try checking that out first. Also, your cast `as Expense` inside the map is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.expenses = expenses.map((expense) => {
            if (typeof expense.due !== 'string') {
              return { ...expense, due: this.formatDate(expense.due.seconds * 1000) };
            } else {
            return expense;
            }
          });
```

I added the else condition and it works without error. Not sure if this is the only way to do this. `if (typeof expense.due !== 'string')` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the type `Expense` as a generic into map, the result would then be typed correctly.

```
this.expense = expenses.map<Expense>((expense) => {
    if (typeof expense.due !== 'string') {
      return { ...expense, due: formatDate(expense.due.seconds * 1000) };
    }
    return expense
});
```

Also you probably want to have a return at the end in the case that it is already a string.